# Date Range Picker date selection issue in Chrome browser

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, google-chrome, jquery-plugins, daterangepicker

I am trying to use the [Date Range Picker](https://github.com/filamentgroup/jQuery-UI-Date-Range-Picker) plugin.

This works fine in Firefox browser. The date selection options does not work in Chrome browser (when I select a date option nothing happens).

I see below logs in the Chrome browser's 'Inspect Element' console:

> daterangepicker.jQuery.js:256Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a
>   function daterangepicker.jQuery.js:159Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call
>   method 'formatDate' of undefined daterangepicker.jQuery.js:171Uncaught
>   TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'datepicker'
>   daterangepicker.jQuery.js:171Uncaught TypeError: Object [object
>   Object] has no method 'datepicker'2
>   daterangepicker.jQuery.js:159Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method
>   'formatDate' of undefined daterangepicker.jQuery.js:171Uncaught
>   TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'datepicker'
>   daterangepicker.jQuery.js:171Uncaught TypeError: Object [object
>   Object] has no method 'datepicker'2
>   daterangepicker.jQuery.js:256Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a
>   function

One interesting thing is, date selection works fine on Chrome if the Date Range Picker plugin code is kept in some folder and just open the `index.html` (demo code). I see this issue only when the plugin is kept on the server.

Please give some hints to fix this.

Comment: you can raise this issue on  github, may be you will get answer there. https://github.com/filamentgroup/jQuery-UI-Date-Range-Picker/issues

Comment: what do you mean by _"kept in the server"_ ? from github ? if yes, not that you have to reference the **raw** version from github (by clicking on the 'raw' link on the upper-right side above the source code).

Comment: @Pramodtech,thank you,I will ask on the github also

Comment: Sorry for the confusion,"kept in the server" means, I see this issue when I include this plugin in my website(running on Apache) and access from chrome browser.I don't see this issue if I just open the demo `index.html` in Chrome browser

Comment: Thanks this worked fine when I used [jquery 1.7.0](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js)
and [jQuery UI 1.8.16](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js)

Answer (score 0):

The fact is for a proper work of the datepicker functionality you have to use [jQuery-UI](http://docs.jquery.com/UI) along with core jQuery library. And of course you should make sure that you have correct version of the libraries. Thereby to use method [$.datepicker.formatDate(format, date)](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/%24.datepicker.formatDate) you need jQuery-UI.

Answer (score 0):

I had sort of the same problem. I think it is caused by Chromes representation of "Date" Fields and the fact that chrome provides its own drop-down date picker.

I just changed the type of the input to "text" and it is working smoothly now just like in Firefox